# How to Run a whole QApplication Asynchronously?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, asynchronous, concurrency

I'm trying to run a modified qt-programm as a library. I need it not not block the main execution.

So what I want to do is to run the QApplication and commence the execution of the main application. How do I achive this?

My first thought was to run it in a seperate thread.

```
void MyClass::execute() {
    someClass = someClass::instance();
    std::thread t1(&MyClass::startApp, this);
    someClass->someFunction();
    someClass->doMoreStuff();
}
void MyClass::startApp() {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.exec();
    QCoreApplication::quit();
}
```

but this results in an `Call to '__invoke' is ambiguous` error. Though I don't know why/where `__invoke` is overwritten and how to handle this error. :(

So how can I accomplish that the QApplication doesn't block the main execution?

Answer (score 0):

Design pattern is totally wrong, QApplication as well as QCoreApplication are not supposed to be multiplied inside one application. What you should do for example is make your own class like:

```
class LibraryCore: public QObject {
}
```

and substitute QApplication to this class inside your future library sources. Then you should implement needed methods in LibraryCore (ones which are used inside application) making them work properly..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you suggest not to use QApplication. When I try not to use it, I get several errors telling me to instanciate a QApplication. Could you maybe explain your plan in more detail?

Comment: are you planning to port Qt application to a library which you want to use with Non-Qt projects? that doesnt look really as a good idea either...

Comment: yes, thats what I am planning to do. I want to use PhantomJS within my application. I need to have access to the PhantomJS WebPages.

Comment: Well, then I would still advise to go the way I proposed and make your application Qt based.. problem is that Qt it's not really a support library but framework which suppose that development follows some rules..

Comment: OH... okay, thanks so far. The plan I had is to have PhantomJS in a blackbox and to interact with it via a simple Interface which is offering the desired functionality. I still havn't really understood what you mean with your answer and how this solves my problem :( sorry.

Comment: step 1. take PhantomJS and make a library out of it, remove thing like new QCoreApplication(..) or whatever inside main() is created. Make a library with certain interface, then build your simple interface using Qt